# What is the purpose of the "~" symbol in Python and how would it alter .isnull()?

Tags: python, symbols, isnull

this will be my first query as I'm pretty new to understanding Python and its intricacies, especially all the symbols. In my attempt to understand the ~ (grave?) symbol I know it's related to binary output. However, I ran into this predicament in a Data Camp practice session. So here's my question: What is the "~" symbol doing in the second line of code?

apps is the dataframe, 'Rating' and 'Size' are columns

```
x: apps_with_size_and_rating_present = apps[(apps['Rating'].isnull()) & (apps['Size'].isnull())]
print(x)
```

This first line, x, does not have the ~ implemented and returns a blank seaborn plot in the terminal:

[image]

However, in the duplicate same line of code including the ~ it does not have the same issue:

```
y: apps_with_size_and_rating_present = apps[(~apps['Rating'].isnull()) & (~apps['Size'].isnull())]
print(y)
```

This second line, y, works as intended

[image]

How does the first line work but not the second? Is the `isnull()` the culprit or am I just not comprehending the functionality of the ~ symbol?

Any information would be appreciated!

I tried understanding the differences by running the same line of code with and without the ~ symbol but do not understand its purpose unless this is a compounded issue. What is the ~ symbol doing to the dataframe and why is it altering the graphical outputs?

Comment: `(apps['Size'],isnull())` should be `(apps['Size'].isnull())`

Comment: (those two lines aren't duplicates until the above is corrected)

Answer (score 1):

`~x` is implemented using the `__invert__` method. For example, `int.__invert__` swaps 0s for 1s and vice versa in the twos'-complement binary representation of an integer.

```
>>> ~8
-9
>>> ~-9
8
```

Other types can define `__invert__` to mean something different. Many libraries use `~`, `&`, and `|` as operators equivalent to `not`, `and`, and `or` (respectively). Since `not x` always means `False if x else True`, you have to pick another operator to implement you own kind of logical negation.

Comment: Are you saying the '~' symbol is interpreted as "not", as in we read for it to plot the apps['Rating' ,'Size'] as "plot this if it is not null?" I found out the graph does not function or display anything without the ~ symbol.